# Run migrations on Dockerfile deploying on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problems making migrations (Django App 4.0.6) on Elastic beanstalk.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PROJECT_DIR=/usr/src/app/
 
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PIPENV_USE_SYSTEM=1

WORKDIR ${PROJECT_DIR}

COPY .  ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
    
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Until here, all works well, but if I try to add `RUN python manage.py migrate` before to `EXPOSE 8000` and make the deploy, I have an 504 error.

I tried to add .ebextensions and config file like this:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

But I don't sure how to activate my env in a Docker, I have an error when I try to make the deploy

```
2022-08-01 03:10:23,328 P28507 [INFO] Command 01_migrate
2022-08-01 03:10:23,331 P28507 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2022-08-01 03:10:23,331 P28507 [INFO]   /bin/sh: /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate: No such file or directory
2022-08-01 03:10:23,331 P28507 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2022-08-01 03:10:23,331 P28507 [ERROR] Exited with error code 1
```

¿What is the best solution for my case?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What EB platform version do you use? Sadly your question does not contain fundamental information about your issue.

Comment: @Marcin Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.17, this is my platform version.

Comment: You don't run migrations in a Dockerfile. It is used to compile a Docker image. Code is run in a container that is based on an image. The best ways to run management commands is via `docker exec -ti running_container command` or for migration to have a start script that applies migration and then start the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using docker compose to deploy, then you can add an entrypoint file and run your migrations and the server command there.

```
# Dockerfile

...

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
    
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/production-entrypoint.sh"]
```

where your `bin/production-entrypoint.sh` file looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
python3 manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Or, if you are using docker compose to deploy, then you can run the commands in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# Dockerfile

...

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - /var/app/current:/usr/src/app
    command: >
      bash -c "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
      && python3 manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

...
```